# Removing Trailing Comma from Query result in Robot Framework

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, robotframework

I am extracting data from MySQL that returns query results as follows:

```
    ${A} = (('HFL', 'TCFLORWWGMAFVFEQLVRN', 'ZZG', 1625, 'SA,WE,DN_IS,', 84))
```

In this part 'SA,WE,DN_IS,' the trailing Comma needs to be removed for data validation. I am using robot framework for this and created loops to extract data from the list and compare individual elements with data on the webpage. So far I did not find any method in Robot Framework, specially Collections Library that I can use to remove the trailing comma. Is there any way to remove it using Robot Framework? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you show us the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the trailing comma or any trailing character in a string by using "Get Substring" keyword of String library.

Example code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    String

*** Variables ***
${a}=    SA,WE,DN_IS,

*** Test Cases ***
Remove last character of a string
    log to console    ${a}
    ${b}=    Get Substring    ${a}    0    -1
    log to console    ${b}
```